# PHP Search/Replace Word in String, & Change the Font Color of Replaced Word(s) Only

Tags: php

I have a text box, a search field, and a replace field. I want to perform a search and replace for the text in my text box and change the color of the font for any of the replaced words. I would like any words that are not replaced to remain the font color they were before the search/replace was performed.

Scratching my head on this one though. Here's the code I've got so far:

```html
<body>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

    <p><br/>
      <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="70" rows="10">
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $search = $_POST["search"];
                $replace = $_POST["replace"];
                $textarea = $_POST["textarea"];

                $newtext = str_replace($search,$replace,$textarea);
                echo $newtext;
            } 
        ?>
    </textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="search">Search :</label>
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="replace">Replace</label>
      <input type="text" name="replace" id="replace" />
    </p>

    <p><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      <label for="textarea"></label>
    </p>

  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: You cann't change the color of the Text inside a Textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the colour of the text within a textarea.

You can however echo it out as text:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $search = $_POST["search"];
        $replace = '<span style="color: #F00;">' . $_POST["replace"] . '</span>';
        $textarea = $_POST["textarea"];

        $newtext = str_replace($search,$replace,$textarea);
        echo $newtext;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Did not know that. Thank you. 

So, I made the change. And I got this result:

This is a <span style="color: #F00;">test</span>.

Comment: So it works, or is there something else you need it to do?

Comment: Took me a moment to understand why a person might want to echo it out as text. The solution is not what I would have hoped for. But, given the fact that what I'm trying to do can't be done, it might be the next best thing.